# How do I plot filled contours with a masked numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contourf

I have a masked numpy array that contains temperature values. It was created by taking the mean temperature from a maximum and minimum temperature dataset. Those datasets also contained masked arrays. I then went ahead and calculated a subtraction from an array titled 'hdd_norm'. This is just a simple array the same size/shape as my mean temp and only contains the number 65.

When I plot using matplotlib's contourf function both my variable hdd (which is the subtraction of my mean temp ('meantempf') from 'hdd_norm' and 'meantempf' itself plot completely normally. I'm attaching the plots here:

[HDD_Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eePdz.jpg)
[Meantempf_Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9JGX.jpg)

I then multiply 'hdd' by 10. I do the same for 'meantempf'. But when I try and add a levels argument into my contourf function it completely breaks the plot for 'hdd' but not for 'meantempf'. It adds data where there isn't and does not scale the values in the way it should. I do not understand why this is. Both are masked arrays.. I have not been able to figure out how or why they need to remain masked but for simplicity purposes I have tried to not mess with that aspect of it. Here's the plots:

[HDD_Broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mATV7.jpg)
[Meantempf_With Levels_Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOPh1.jpg)

The only difference is that 'hdd' is the result of a subtraction of masked arrays but 'meantempf' is the addition as you can see in my code which I'm attaching. Why would this make a difference? What is the difference between these arrays and how can I add in a levels argument into my contourf function for 'hdd'? I'm really stumped by this and my lack of knowledge of masked arrays is probably the root of the problem here but I just am lost on what to do next.

```
from copy import copy
import pygrib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
import cartopy.crs as crs
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeat
from cartopy.feature import OCEAN, LAKES
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import time
import io
import glob
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature
start_time = time.time()

files_min = glob.glob("/Users/mikhailk/Desktop/ds.mint.bin")
files_max = glob.glob("/Users/mikhailk/Desktop/ds.maxt.bin")

pathancillary = '/Users/mikhailk/Desktop/Climate Regions/Southern/'

b = (1377,2145)        
b = np.zeros(b)
c = []
hdd_norm = np.full((1377,2145), 65, dtype = 'float64')
hdd_norm_ma = np.ma.asarray(hdd_norm)
df = pd.DataFrame([])

for (i,j) in zip(files_min, files_max):
    filename_min = i
    filename_max = j
    grbs_min = pygrib.open(filename_min)
    grbs_max = pygrib.open(filename_max)
    
    range_times = np.arange(2,4,1)
    
    for element in range_times:
        #time = element
        element = int(element)
        grb_min = grbs_min[element]
        grb_max = grbs_max[element]
        
        #Minimum Temp Dataset
        tempk_min = grb_min.values
        date_time = grb_min.validDate
        lats, lons = grb_min.latlons()
        
        #Maximum Temp Dataset
        tempk_max = grb_max.values
        date_time = grb_max.validDate
        lats, lons = grb_max.latlons()
        
        ##Getting the Date & Time String
        date_time_str = str(date_time)
        timestr = date_time_str[11:19]
        datestr = date_time_str[0:10]
        
        #valid_date_time_str = datestr + '_' + timestr
        
        #Mean Temp
        meantempk = (tempk_min + tempk_max) / 2
        
        #Mean Temp in F
        meantempf = (meantempk - 273.15) * (9/5) + 32
        
        #Heating Degree Days
        hdd = hdd_norm - meantempf
        #     c = hdd + 10
        #     b = c
        #     print(np.max(hdd))
        #     print(np.max(b))
        # hdd_total = c
        
    # Create the figure
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,14))
    ax = plt.axes(projection = crs.LambertConformal(central_longitude = -95, 
                                                    central_latitude = 35,
                                                    standard_parallels = (30,60)))
    #extent = [-123, -103, 31, 50] #Western
    #extent = [-112, -94, 36.5, 50] #High Plains
    #extent = [-97.5, -80, 35.6, 50] #Midwestern
    #extent = [-82, -68, 36.0, 50] #Northeast
    #extent = [-88.8, -76.0, 24.2, 40.10] #Southeast
    #extent = [-107, -82, 24, 37.2] #Southern
    extent = [-121, -73, 24, 50] #Conus
    ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    
    # Add the Temperature Contours
    hdd = hdd #* 10 
    meantempf = meantempf * 10
    # hdd_new = hdd.filled()
    # hdd_nm = ma.getdata(hdd)
    #hdd[hdd<0] = np.nan
    #a = hdd.clip(0)
    levels = np.arange(0,110,10)
    #vmin, vmax = 0, 800
    #hdd_contours = plt.contourf(lons, lats, hdd, cmap=get_cmap("gist_rainbow"), transform = crs.PlateCarree(), zorder = 1)
    hdd_contours = plt.contourf(lons, lats, hdd, levels = levels, cmap=get_cmap("gist_rainbow"), transform = crs.PlateCarree(), zorder = 1)
    levels = np.arange(0,120,20)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(hdd_contours, ax=ax, ticks = levels, orientation="horizontal", pad=.05)
    cbar.set_ticks([])
    
    # Download and add the states, coastlines, counties
    states = NaturalEarthFeature(category="cultural", scale="50m",
                                  facecolor="none",
                                  name="admin_1_states_provinces_shp")
    ax.add_feature(states, linewidth=1.0, edgecolor="black")
    ax.coastlines('50m', linewidth=1.5)
    reader = shpreader.Reader(pathancillary+'southern.shp')
    counties = list(reader.geometries())
    COUNTIES = cfeat.ShapelyFeature(counties, ccrs.PlateCarree())
    #ax.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='lightgray', edgecolor='black', zorder=2)
    ax.add_feature(OCEAN.with_scale('50m'), edgecolor='black', lw=1, zorder=2)
    ax.add_feature(LAKES.with_scale('50m'), edgecolor='black', lw=1, zorder=2)
```

Thank you for taking a look.

https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.conus/VP.001-003/ds.maxt.bin

https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.conus/VP.001-003/ds.mint.bin

Comment: Its not at all clear what you mean by "breaks the plot", and we cannot reproduce your plot because there is no data.

Comment: Notice how there is data where there wasn't data before on the HDD_Broken graphic. It is South of the US border with Mexico and North of the border in Canada.  Also all the values should scale by 10, but instead a large swath of the area is now just one value/solid color. Clearly what I'm expecting to happen does not happen. I am appending my code and adding the 2 files so that you an try and reproduce the result. I wasn't sure if it was necessary to provide the data, but I will do that. Thank you for taking a look!